# How to use max_by to find the parent (and its siblings) key that contains the highest value of a key inside an array?

Tags: json, max, jq

I'v tried using max_by with these two commands to get what I wanted.

```
#1. cat file | jq '[.tx[].vout[]] | max_by(.value)'
#2. cat file | jq '[.tx[]] | max_by(.vout[].value)'
```

And this two commands gave me different max values. ( the value key has float value. Noted that I've also tried to use "tonumber" option but nothing special happened )
The #1 output is always right, but its output doesn't include parent keys.
The #2 output sometimes got the answer right as #1, sometimes it didn't, but it includes the parent keys that I'd like to have.

Anybody could show me what's wrong here?

Json example:

```
{
  "hash": "00000000000000000001241066f08f95165581bcfc9bf322cb8fe2bfb6b2f06c",
  "confirmations": 1,
  "height": 786329,
  "version": 591831040,
  "versionHex": "2346a000",
  "merkleroot": "93fae4566cf6de6321e0cd1ed4ab9ac600189d26d7d61ef6c41487752344bf49",
  "time": 1682050350,
  "mediantime": 1682049479,
  "nonce": 3398206502,
  "bits": "1705c739",
  "difficulty": 48712405953118.43,
  "chainwork": "00000000000000000000000000000000000000004630bda1645c6b5192c287b4",
  "nTx": 1800,
  "previousblockhash": "0000000000000000000266435d01b562713c63d22844afbc2ddabfeaabab0ed0",
  "strippedsize": 751963,
  "size": 1737058,
  "weight": 3992947,
  "tx": [
    {
      "txid": "273baace700870d378d68b9d386520f0b3b3796521748c36b6f494865725728a",
      "hash": "c7fc6635d004cc714b5395e370b7287a76ad3ae7c59bad86f92701852dd46504",
      "version": 2,
      "size": 214,
      "vsize": 187,
      "weight": 748,
      "locktime": 0,
      "vin": [
        {
          "coinbase": "0399ff0b042e0d42642f466f756e6472792055534120506f6f6c202364726f70676f6c642f03e2e49b2e58000000000000",
          "txinwitness": [
            "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
          ],
          "sequence": 4294967295
        }
      ],
      "vout": [
        {
          "value": 6.36518171,
          "n": 0,
          "scriptPubKey": {
            "asm": "0 35f6de260c9f3bdee47524c473a6016c0c055cb9",
            "hex": "001435f6de260c9f3bdee47524c473a6016c0c055cb9",
            "address": "bc1qxhmdufsvnuaaaer4ynz88fspdsxq2h9e9cetdj",
            "type": "witness_v0_keyhash"
          }
        },
        {
          "value": 0.00000000,
          "n": 1,
          "scriptPubKey": {
            "asm": "OP_RETURN aa21a9edb389e4fde6f6da8aa655288ffc460e8c00a169fa9420a496fdc1e60bf4dcf8d7",
            "hex": "6a24aa21a9edb389e4fde6f6da8aa655288ffc460e8c00a169fa9420a496fdc1e60bf4dcf8d7",
            "type": "nulldata"
          }
        }
      ],
      "hex": "020000000001010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ffffffff310399ff0b042e0d42642f466f756e6472792055534120506f6f6c202364726f70676f6c642f03e2e49b2e58000000000000ffffffff021b7ff0250000000016001435f6de260c9f3bdee47524c473a6016c0c055cb90000000000000000266a24aa21a9edb389e4fde6f6da8aa655288ffc460e8c00a169fa9420a496fdc1e60bf4dcf8d70120000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
    },
    {
      "txid": "82cad0c8bf23f1e0ada86df5e4cbcd508245ab45618f2424ac4f354445ae1e81",
      "hash": "45512a05a5ca929e23364a7f06a0fa10defed2ebdc77e74f1e9d08cc64245b6b",
      "version": 1,
      "size": 414,
      "vsize": 224,
      "weight": 894,
      "locktime": 0,
      "vin": [
        {
          "txid": "a1a842e9de8482e84e42a096396465e1c2367101b5676a4b94404c8e39fc784c",
          "vout": 2,
          "scriptSig": {
            "asm": "",
            "hex": ""
          },
          "txinwitness": [
            "",
            "30440220222e21db0d6ef8e7541ba89ac706128cf5cddd1154420d2236532c00b69d406f02201563447fb0d612fab8565a6b694b904a1fe0212b45d0eb0b0a120b95c0c70e5601",
            "304402200d885f1bb76de47ba636fa2e2370a017d563da6a4f269fd4a9bc4a1e0bda4e360220592a248b2f6b1b894becba1eb3452438ea164a4a27201bd8d760f47d0692e56401",
            "52210375e00eb72e29da82b89367947f29ef34afb75e8654f6ea368e0acdfd92976b7c2103a1b26313f430c4b15bb1fdce663207659d8cac749a0e53d70eff01874496feff2103c96d495bfdd5ba4145e3e046fee45e84a8a48ad05bd8dbb395c011a32cf9f88053ae"
          ],
          "sequence": 4294967295
        }
      ],
      "vout": [
        {
          "value": 0.02400000,
          "n": 0,
          "scriptPubKey": {
            "asm": "OP_HASH160 e0bd422a0555d8cfad1bdbf2781830a0329e442c OP_EQUAL",
            "hex": "a914e0bd422a0555d8cfad1bdbf2781830a0329e442c87",
            "address": "3NBL1RQjEr4vDbqmSMWeV64oDge7dSRRGp",
            "type": "scripthash"
          }
        },
        {
          "value": 0.00160719,
          "n": 1,
          "scriptPubKey": {
            "asm": "OP_DUP OP_HASH160 57155f4180f1f0a1b15c8f473ddb2cd9103171c5 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
            "hex": "76a91457155f4180f1f0a1b15c8f473ddb2cd9103171c588ac",
            "address": "18wTPebwqMZDqujSZfj8fchFRTP65Ynvoj",
            "type": "pubkeyhash"
          }
        },
        {
          "value": 0.01845731,
          "n": 2,
          "scriptPubKey": {
            "asm": "0 701a8d401c84fb13e6baf169d59684e17abd9fa216c8cc5b9fc63d622ff8c58d",
            "hex": "0020701a8d401c84fb13e6baf169d59684e17abd9fa216c8cc5b9fc63d622ff8c58d",
            "address": "bc1qwqdg6squsna38e46795at95yu9atm8azzmyvckulcc7kytlcckxswvvzej",
            "type": "witness_v0_scripthash"
          }
        }
      ],
      "fee": 0.00040000,
      "hex": "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"
    },
    {
      "txid": "802ef44673ff9c90bae2a9790aba0a71176cef71f5c7dfde723401beecef6d5a",
      "hash": "41b3672f668abdb721289fe91d894a40bff1424123ee008ee4b7fe1d438b3dc5",
      "version": 2,
      "size": 223,
      "vsize": 141,
      "weight": 562,
      "locktime": 0,
      "vin": [
        {
          "txid": "79d114144fea2914a5019967dba85ff34d5ee897d34ae1bf5216c2ac49fe738d",
          "vout": 3,
          "scriptSig": {
            "asm": "",
            "hex": ""
          },
          "txinwitness": [
            "3045022100cee123978849318825c437d2965bb89177cf4efe3a1729fb5eaee8bc18911b9602200d7c9ac92eb8339489509ea3306f1a897dbec757507c61bb943252cb540bf79701",
            "026e5628506ecd33242e5ceb5fdafe4d3066b5c0f159b3c05a621ef65f177ea286"
          ],
          "sequence": 4294967293
        }
      ],
      "vout": [
        {
          "value": 0.00600000,
          "n": 0,
          "scriptPubKey": {
            "asm": "0 afb3eb8b9edbcc83709b374d1c581c1e263dcad5",
            "hex": "0014afb3eb8b9edbcc83709b374d1c581c1e263dcad5",
            "address": "bc1q47e7hzu7m0xgxuymxax3ckqurcnrmjk4vlr8mh",
            "type": "witness_v0_keyhash"
          }
        },
        {
          "value": 8.89321842,
          "n": 1,
          "scriptPubKey": {
            "asm": "0 f60834ef165253c571b11ce9fa74e46692fc5ec1",
            "hex": "0014f60834ef165253c571b11ce9fa74e46692fc5ec1",
            "address": "bc1q7cyrfmck2ffu2ud3rn5l5a8yv6f0chkp0zpemf",
            "type": "witness_v0_keyhash"
          }
        }
      ],
      "fee": 0.00022032,
      "hex": "020000000001018d73fe49acc21652bfe14ad397e85e4df35fa8db679901a51429ea4f1414d1790300000000fdffffff02c027090000000000160014afb3eb8b9edbcc83709b374d1c581c1e263dcad572f9013500000000160014f60834ef165253c571b11ce9fa74e46692fc5ec102483045022100cee123978849318825c437d2965bb89177cf4efe3a1729fb5eaee8bc18911b9602200d7c9ac92eb8339489509ea3306f1a897dbec757507c61bb943252cb540bf7970121026e5628506ecd33242e5ceb5fdafe4d3066b5c0f159b3c05a621ef65f177ea28600000000"
    },
    {
      "txid": "d007aa4ef0fdd0add723551e4e43a7214692491c0dd44d8bb93bffd44c9799da",
      "hash": "758e37a729cc6ab78c8f5eb9ad360b2b93836ce0c850db5689aca2d258d08f4a",
      "version": 2,
      "size": 223,
      "vsize": 141,
      "weight": 562,
      "locktime": 0,
      "vin": [
        {
          "txid": "763ae3655896af8102d50e536d74f8a4643cb31153c7b3479dde2cff286cf83e",
          "vout": 1,
          "scriptSig": {
            "asm": "",
            "hex": ""
          },
          "txinwitness": [
            "3045022100c707a290598ead494f7c0ae0cca6e7c352b64910975a796148d11a42f47405e80220557d67f1f35a1c10b8ef27ba85b841779dd0c405d3f5f7c5e3bc9e573943e3e701",
            "02076c2a3862869b95bdadfaaf8bf3376b6ee4bf450aca9587aaa961f7b22533df"
          ],
          "sequence": 4294967293
        }
      ],
      "vout": [
        {
          "value": 0.08400000,
          "n": 0,
          "scriptPubKey": {
            "asm": "0 86a1c36b7ec85975f1d852f0c39e69d16b736373",
            "hex": "001486a1c36b7ec85975f1d852f0c39e69d16b736373",
            "address": "bc1qs6sux6m7epvhtuwc2tcv88nf694hxcmnmzt670",
            "type": "witness_v0_keyhash"
          }
        },
        {
          "value": 14.32349940,
          "n": 1,
          "scriptPubKey": {
            "asm": "0 16ee7494a93f327c10afe94c04fdcb1dc3744600",
            "hex": "001416ee7494a93f327c10afe94c04fdcb1dc3744600",
            "address": "bc1qzmh8f99f8ue8cy90a9xqflwtrhphg3sq76srhe",
            "type": "witness_v0_keyhash"
          }
        }
      ],
      "fee": 0.00022032,
      "hex": "020000000001013ef86c28ff2cde9d47b3c75311b33c64a4f8746d530ed50281af965865e33a760100000000fdffffff02802c80000000000016001486a1c36b7ec85975f1d852f0c39e69d16b736373f4ec5f550000000016001416ee7494a93f327c10afe94c04fdcb1dc374460002483045022100c707a290598ead494f7c0ae0cca6e7c352b64910975a796148d11a42f47405e80220557d67f1f35a1c10b8ef27ba85b841779dd0c405d3f5f7c5e3bc9e573943e3e7012102076c2a3862869b95bdadfaaf8bf3376b6ee4bf450aca9587aaa961f7b22533df00000000"
    },
    {
      "txid": "7cb5c8d5e9aecac1b96bd17d9cbbfa32a2a692f6fae997f648953a8aa92bc74f",
      "hash": "9320dbabfa8449c8f124ad90296e9b5f7f39c30735750f4e79a32bb25ec4969c",
      "version": 2,
      "size": 254,
      "vsize": 173,
      "weight": 689,
      "locktime": 0,
      "vin": [
        {
          "txid": "6c90ce72395ae4b8a15f7569fc1824a6f7b11fd6ad80ed4ddf01a7d72d1616a7",
          "vout": 3,
          "scriptSig": {
            "asm": "",
            "hex": ""
          },
          "txinwitness": [
            "304402200f29e2be998dd991460dbaafc639cf5ca031a0057f099f56052b44297c6206cf0220488e696aed1503aac68e3fb916e2304b1681ad5e4265b8f571c898afd92e96f701",
            "026e5628506ecd33242e5ceb5fdafe4d3066b5c0f159b3c05a621ef65f177ea286"
          ],
          "sequence": 4294967293
        }
      ],
      "vout": [
        {
          "value": 0.00375950,
          "n": 0,
          "scriptPubKey": {
            "asm": "OP_HASH160 6feb94fd2b9e4e9d1afb90c5c09340c578d5e410 OP_EQUAL",
            "hex": "a9146feb94fd2b9e4e9d1afb90c5c09340c578d5e41087",
            "address": "3Bto9MriAUnocAzE36yL7GUshApeSMw9iq",
            "type": "scripthash"
          }
        },
        {
          "value": 0.00949735,
          "n": 1,
          "scriptPubKey": {
            "asm": "0 00914aa5f061ac9f5f542ec580c619e48c829b86",
            "hex": "001400914aa5f061ac9f5f542ec580c619e48c829b86",
            "address": "bc1qqzg54f0svxkf7h659mzcp3seujxg9xux6lgx38",
            "type": "witness_v0_keyhash"
          }
        },
        {
          "value": 5.93817769,
          "n": 2,
          "scriptPubKey": {
            "asm": "0 f60834ef165253c571b11ce9fa74e46692fc5ec1",
            "hex": "0014f60834ef165253c571b11ce9fa74e46692fc5ec1",
            "address": "bc1q7cyrfmck2ffu2ud3rn5l5a8yv6f0chkp0zpemf",
            "type": "witness_v0_keyhash"
          }
        }
      ],
      "fee": 0.00026928,
      "hex": "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"
    },
    {
      "txid": "b080e7e39d6db4414a25c8c37b642a00e5e5c29592b3ef475754448ccccfb75e",
      "hash": "5127274b6b27919c7cbb14620089c68b2b572156a555a790a8c04c5ad09bc94f",
      "version": 2,
      "size": 317,
      "vsize": 235,
      "weight": 938,
      "locktime": 0,
      "vin": [
        {
          "txid": "99342b19982f6a2d9a244cc2b22884cea413ec5d682a6d8e1a17f88bcfd7b14e",
          "vout": 3,
          "scriptSig": {
            "asm": "",
            "hex": ""
          },
          "txinwitness": [
            "3045022100cfdf46bf202f8806570a6afbafcfd0672619d5432533748f0641f88befb1f1790220321b248dea29c2b832c799f40de041e2dabb020e751a76814f61272c9123526d01",
            "026e5628506ecd33242e5ceb5fdafe4d3066b5c0f159b3c05a621ef65f177ea286"
          ],
          "sequence": 4294967293
        }
      ],
      "vout": [
        {
          "value": 0.01880000,
          "n": 0,
          "scriptPubKey": {
            "asm": "0 e59390350f807c6930f5711e61f68a94fadc910f",
            "hex": "0014e59390350f807c6930f5711e61f68a94fadc910f",
            "address": "bc1qukfeqdg0sp7xjv84wy0xra52jnadeyg04zgldm",
            "type": "witness_v0_keyhash"
          }
        },
        {
          "value": 0.00392486,
          "n": 1,
          "scriptPubKey": {
            "asm": "0 ecd18d448745fb48b6423f5b2c1cc381e593fee5",
            "hex": "0014ecd18d448745fb48b6423f5b2c1cc381e593fee5",
            "address": "bc1qangc63y8gha53djz8adjc8xrs8je8lh92nalf5",
            "type": "witness_v0_keyhash"
          }
        },
        {
          "value": 0.03725620,
          "n": 2,
          "scriptPubKey": {
            "asm": "0 7e60bff1b82c59aa482c0a4b32e90373ff59dd6b",
            "hex": "00147e60bff1b82c59aa482c0a4b32e90373ff59dd6b",
            "address": "bc1q0estludc93v65jpvpf9n96grw0l4nhttxjdcg5",
            "type": "witness_v0_keyhash"
          }
        },
        {
          "value": 0.00495770,
          "n": 3,
          "scriptPubKey": {
            "asm": "OP_HASH160 6dc9a2c492c64090bc5cc4a6ddc2ff87be61a000 OP_EQUAL",
            "hex": "a9146dc9a2c492c64090bc5cc4a6ddc2ff87be61a00087",
            "address": "3BhX8MYo2Xb9T46GF5m8BfzmXGWSMPpnx1",
            "type": "scripthash"
          }
        },
        {
          "value": 4.25211103,
          "n": 4,
          "scriptPubKey": {
            "asm": "0 f60834ef165253c571b11ce9fa74e46692fc5ec1",
            "hex": "0014f60834ef165253c571b11ce9fa74e46692fc5ec1",
            "address": "bc1q7cyrfmck2ffu2ud3rn5l5a8yv6f0chkp0zpemf",
            "type": "witness_v0_keyhash"
          }
        }
      ],
      "fee": 0.00036414,
      "hex": "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"
    },
    {
      "txid": "e741044ca9a20a860c8f64f43aab9834d61e76370cd81d2963ee48bd3f731e01",
      "hash": "b2ccc985c58632a0bd4acffde1e26c984c48c9a87ecb323959f9ccfb90a0d99c",
      "version": 2,
      "size": 317,
      "vsize": 236,
      "weight": 941,
      "locktime": 0,
      "vin": [
        {
          "txid": "8619d1f5f3236bf42aa567994fc431c0906bfc8ba80d842aa568c2dd3563d6ec",
          "vout": 2,
          "scriptSig": {
            "asm": "",
            "hex": ""
          },
          "txinwitness": [
            "30440220605800a14d1237e281b5d888eaf24531ea431fc5c512e9672e2aca2222dc2e9e02206f8d757acef8a94b2a787c03fafd1f0fd92afbe08be3c450dab1137c104b843101",
            "026e5628506ecd33242e5ceb5fdafe4d3066b5c0f159b3c05a621ef65f177ea286"
          ],
          "sequence": 4294967293
        }
      ],
      "vout": [
        {
          "value": 0.00982110,
          "n": 0,
          "scriptPubKey": {
            "asm": "OP_HASH160 3970e94b1d2d9440b7b9316dd3cb66728a22860b OP_EQUAL",
            "hex": "a9143970e94b1d2d9440b7b9316dd3cb66728a22860b87",
            "address": "36vjhh9DY5jZhaKFpgPw9z6DSKXWLJXFJQ",
            "type": "scripthash"
          }
        },
        {
          "value": 0.00079070,
          "n": 1,
          "scriptPubKey": {
            "asm": "0 07154d960f9b7c044eb3b7e48a45b2ae5f58289f",
            "hex": "001407154d960f9b7c044eb3b7e48a45b2ae5f58289f",
            "address": "bc1qqu25m9s0nd7qgn4nkljg53dj4e04s2ylft0fyx",
            "type": "witness_v0_keyhash"
          }
        },
        {
          "value": 0.00843110,
          "n": 2,
          "scriptPubKey": {
            "asm": "0 d3e3389b2bbdcb50e4c2c826a95ed6d92e513d93",
            "hex": "0014d3e3389b2bbdcb50e4c2c826a95ed6d92e513d93",
            "address": "bc1q603n3xethh94pexzeqn2jhkkmyh9z0vnzx4ctw",
            "type": "witness_v0_keyhash"
          }
        },
        {
          "value": 0.00711090,
          "n": 3,
          "scriptPubKey": {
            "asm": "OP_HASH160 5149cd5ac5b95165994920f92e7bd9c9d597a94d OP_EQUAL",
            "hex": "a9145149cd5ac5b95165994920f92e7bd9c9d597a94d87",
            "address": "396q4wr3q6QDjMK3oGypoqK1Dsxezy9WHp",
            "type": "scripthash"
          }
        },
        {
          "value": 0.58401219,
          "n": 4,
          "scriptPubKey": {
            "asm": "0 f60834ef165253c571b11ce9fa74e46692fc5ec1",
            "hex": "0014f60834ef165253c571b11ce9fa74e46692fc5ec1",
            "address": "bc1q7cyrfmck2ffu2ud3rn5l5a8yv6f0chkp0zpemf",
            "type": "witness_v0_keyhash"
          }
        }
      ],
      "fee": 0.00036567,
      "hex": "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"
    },
    {
      "txid": "af6c40234770c8e3fac9bfc14b5dc4ef59223407e8a24320233d3b89c36500c0",
      "hash": "af6c40234770c8e3fac9bfc14b5dc4ef59223407e8a24320233d3b89c36500c0",
      "version": 2,
      "size": 372,
      "vsize": 372,
      "weight": 1488,
      "locktime": 0,
      "vin": [
        {
          "txid": "5b8da0a71ca0a68782553e0bec7515a342490cea18c0913c7de710e66788c74a",
          "vout": 1,
          "scriptSig": {
            "asm": "30440220043697d59c9c7ca0cfc6f2bb64997b04c6ac6da104d0d0aec410f80fca448c91022059c21473dc079fac56fa90efec44c782513ad9cf5b0fe562dd55881c82bfc3ea[ALL] 03786af4b32017ec640dba2d2a7e1fd5aa4a231a658e4cbc114d51c031576e19bc",
            "hex": "4730440220043697d59c9c7ca0cfc6f2bb64997b04c6ac6da104d0d0aec410f80fca448c91022059c21473dc079fac56fa90efec44c782513ad9cf5b0fe562dd55881c82bfc3ea012103786af4b32017ec640dba2d2a7e1fd5aa4a231a658e4cbc114d51c031576e19bc"
          },
          "sequence": 4294967293
        },
        {
          "txid": "21973ecb9ed1dc2d656aee5451cbb49d93f63f4713da4ad5f0dd0d22119efe24",
          "vout": 1,
          "scriptSig": {
            "asm": "304402203ec8247ad3fce9936f2ce9b32f84b353df87acf9f66322bce5e62a62375961f002202c8f6d6b6b236d16078ebe1446f4e0359629491dd89eb5acdbcfad9395e58f4a[ALL] 03786af4b32017ec640dba2d2a7e1fd5aa4a231a658e4cbc114d51c031576e19bc",
            "hex": "47304402203ec8247ad3fce9936f2ce9b32f84b353df87acf9f66322bce5e62a62375961f002202c8f6d6b6b236d16078ebe1446f4e0359629491dd89eb5acdbcfad9395e58f4a012103786af4b32017ec640dba2d2a7e1fd5aa4a231a658e4cbc114d51c031576e19bc"
          },
          "sequence": 4294967293
        }
      ],
      "vout": [
        {
          "value": 5.73600000,
          "n": 0,
          "scriptPubKey": {
            "asm": "OP_DUP OP_HASH160 8cf220cdf093afa35a7b3b689fe16050afc8c829 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
            "hex": "76a9148cf220cdf093afa35a7b3b689fe16050afc8c82988ac",
            "address": "1DrFfDSfUZMBP6YrSR4ug2mFgigfwfvETm",
            "type": "pubkeyhash"
          }
        },
        {
          "value": 45.68360097,
          "n": 1,
          "scriptPubKey": {
            "asm": "OP_DUP OP_HASH160 cebb2851a9c7cfe2582c12ecaf7f3ff4383d1dc0 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
            "hex": "76a914cebb2851a9c7cfe2582c12ecaf7f3ff4383d1dc088ac",
            "address": "1Kr6QSydW9bFQG1mXiPNNu6WpJGmUa9i1g",
            "type": "pubkeyhash"
          }
        }
      ],
      "fee": 0.00056417,
      "hex": "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"
    }
 ]
}
```

I've figured it out to work around with this solution:

```
max=$(cat file | jq '[.tx[].vout[]] | max_by(.value) | .value')
cat file | jq '.tx[] | select(.vout[].value=='$max')
```

And I would get what I wanted. But it made me feel stupid, so please enlighten me with a concise solution.

Comment: Would you show some example JSON objects you want to filter with `jq`?

Comment: Yes, I just edited the question to add the json.

Comment: Is this [`jqplay.org` example](https://jqplay.org/s/mmtTj2hrFLi) close to what you are looking for?  Even if it produces the correct output, I expect it could be greatly improved.

Comment: to be honest, your solution works well, and just a lil bit better than my stupid solution ( just added in the question ). The main problem I wanted to solve is how to get the parent key with max_by filter in a really concise way ( and i think it could be done ) Anyway, thank you very much for helping me^^

Comment: I'm no `jq` expert, hopefully you'll get a better response.

Comment: Your solution is 180 bytes, my not-smart-enough solution is 83 bytes. `jq '.tx[] | select(.vout[].value=='$(cat file | jq '[.tx[].vout[].value] | max')')'` and both have the same result.

Comment: yeah, thanks a lot for spending time on my question<3

Comment: My solution only goes through the JSON once.  ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've figured it out to work around with this solution

Your solution can easily be simplified so that only one call to jq is necessary.  Further refinement leads to:

```
.tx 
| ([.[].vout[].value]|max) as $max
| .[] | select(.vout[].value==$max)
```

However, you probably want to avoid duplications:

```
.tx 
| ([.[].vout[].value]|max) as $max
|   .[] | select(any(.vout[]; .value == $max))
```

The above will of course yield all the maximal values (i.e. potentially more than one).  If you wanted to be sure of only getting the first, you could (for example) use `first`:

```
.tx 
| ([.[].vout[].value]|max) as $max
| first(.[] | select(any(.vout[]; .value == $max)))
```

or simply:

```
.tx | max_by( [.vout[].value] | max)
```

#### Follow-up Question

For a large file, it would be better to use a stream-oriented version of `max`, and likewise for `min`, e.g.:

```
def max(s): reduce s as $x (null; if . == null or $x > . then $x else . end);
def min(s): reduce s as $x (null; if . == null or $x < . then $x else . end);

.tx | (max_by( max(.vout[].value)), min_by( min(.vout[].value) ) )
```

Comment: Does `.tx | max_by(.vout[].value)` work too?

Comment: The final solution is exactly what I imagined it should be, really concise, thank you peak so much. @rickhg12hs That is the #2 attempt I posted in the question, sometimes work, sometimes wrong, I don't really understand why :D

Comment: Please see "Follow-up Question".

Comment: Hi Peak, May I ask another related question here? How to exclude the object that doesn't has the field that I'm using min_by at? I mean the value of the field ranges from zero and onward, When using min_by, it always returns the object that doesn't has the field instead of the the object that has the field with zero value. The JSON example is also the same one in the main question. The field I'm using min_by at is "fee".

Comment: @11100100 - You could use `// empty`. If I understand the question correctly, you'd write `min( .vout[].value // empty)`; if not, please ask a separate SO Q, preferably with a very small example.

Comment: Not really what I mean. But `// empty` could give me some clue about null value and minimum value. Trying to do more research to solve it myself. If still can't, sure will reach you with another SO Q. Many thanks.